# How to access same method name which belongs to different namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I an getting error while accessing  "Invoke" method.

1. I have `Invoke` method which belongs to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace
2. I have another `Invoke` in below method which belongs to  `System.Reflection` namespace

Now, when I run the application It shows me the error

> Multiple public 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' methods are available.)

Both the invoke methods are use as below

1.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
  var ctx = context.Request;
  var ctx1 = context.Request.Headers;
  await this.next(context);
}
```

2.

```
private async Task<int> ProcessEventAsync()
{
return await ((Task<int>)concreteType.GetMethod("HandleAsync").Invoke(handler, new object[] { integrationEvent })).ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

Comment: why cant you invoke the method with the namespace only to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @Samaritan_Learner I have updated the question. Please guide me according.

Comment: I've just realised that my answer only works for static methods, or for identifying classes, while Invoke is a method of an object. That error implies that the object you're calling has multiple Invoke methods.  Please try to post a minimal, complete example that we can use to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespace to identify the version that you want. E.g.

```
System.Reflection.Invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

use using 
for example,you have two class.their namesapce are

- namespace1.YourClass
- namespace2.YourClass

when use them,your file may like this.

```
using s1=namespace1;
using s2=namespace2;

namesapce ConsoleApp{
    public class Test{
        public void Method(){
            s1.YourClass = new s1.YourClass();
            s2.YourClass = new s2.YourClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NamespaceName.ClassName.FunctionName`
and in your case, it would be 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Invoke` & `System.Reflection.Invoke`